# what should i learn to start creating a module in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I want to create a Module in OpenERP but I don't know what should I know ? 
I'm a .net developer with 2 years experience.
my question is :
besides Python what should I learn ?
and how can I start being productive ASAP ?
thank you for your response :)

Comment: why should not take openerp training? just pay and take training

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here usually we try to solve problems related with code, not how to learn to do a particular thing, see this manual [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to know basic python, To learn Python you can use [byte of python](http://files.swaroopch.com/python/byte_of_python.pdf) book

Training is best option I suppose but if you want yo learn by your self then you can
download [OpenERP technical Memento](http://doc.openerp.com/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf). which will help you get kick start.